# Enable UISplitViewController's UIPopoverController on view appearance

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

When using a `UISplitViewController`, I can enable a `UIPopoverController` when the device is on portrait orientation, and disable on landscape with the following methods:

```
// Popover is accessed with a swipe to right gesture
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
  _popover = pc;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
  _popover = nil;
}
```

However, if user is already on portrait when the view is loaded, the popover will not be enabled, unless the user rotate the device to landscape then back to portrait. I'd like to know how to enable it from the beginning, when the view appears.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem I've seen is that you may be setting the splitViewController.delegate too late, such as in "ViewDidLoad".  I usually see it implemented in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions section, or in your detailViewController's awakeFromNib method.